# Bootstrap data toggle collapse only on small device

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can you use Bootstraps collapse function so that it only applies on mobile device without duplication code i.e I know how to acheive it using the visible and hidden classes but I'm looking for a more elegant solution where I don't have to duplicate the code.

currently the following will apply the toggle on all screen sizes:

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="1">
      Link with href
    </a>

    <div class="collapse" id="1">

    </div>

 <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="2">
      Link with href
    </a>

    <div class="collapse" id="2">

    </div>

 <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="3">
      Link with href
    </a>

    <div class="collapse" id="3">

    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do it based on window size. If it's less than `767px` you can add `data-toggle` attribute with JavaScript.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/t1etnj5w/4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   console.log($(window).width());
   if ($(window).width() < 767) {
     $('.collapse-div').each(function(){
       $(this).attr('data-toggle','collapse'); 
     })
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it is an old question I came across this question because I had a similar issue. Maybe my solution to make bootstrap 4 collapsable elements responsive is helpful to somebody.

Design principles:

1. My approach follows the mobile first (i.e. small screens first) principle from bootstrap and uses the break-points of bootstrap.
2. It uses the "show" class from bootstrap 4 which bootstrap uses for default the toggling value of the collapsed object to be expanded. And which bootstrap 4 changes each time the user toggles the view manually.
3. My code adds for the class attribute the responsive values "show-*" where * stands for the bootstrap standard breakpoints sm, md, lg, xl.

How to use:

1. Build regular bootstrap 4 html code. In the place where you would put the "show" value to default a collapsible element to be displayed expanded place instead one of the responsible "show-*" values.
2. Include the jquery code-snippet below in your javascript code.

What it does:

1. The collapsible element will be shown collapsed on small screens up to the specified breakpoint from where on it will be displayed expanded by default.
2. Resizing the browser window will invoke a new test of document width and adjust the "show" effect to the new width.
3. Manual toggling by users is still possible. But any resize forces the collapsible elements to their responsive default value again.

```
    function responsiveCollapseView() {
        let desktopView = $(document).width();
        if(desktopView >= "1200"){
            $('.show-xl, .show-lg, .show-md, .show-sm').addClass('show')
        }
        else if(desktopView >= "992"){
            $('.show-lg, .show-md, .show-sm').addClass('show')
            $('.show-xl').removeClass('show')
        }
        else if(desktopView >= "768"){
            $('.show-md, .show-sm').addClass('show')
            $('.show-lg, .show-xl').removeClass('show')
        }
        else if(desktopView >= "576"){
            $('.show-sm').addClass('show')
            $('.show-xl, .show-lg, .show-md').removeClass('show')
        }
        else {
            $('.show-xl, .show-lg, .show-md, .show-sm').removeClass('show')
        }
    }
    $(function() {
        responsiveCollapseView();
        $(window).resize(function () {
            responsiveCollapseView()
        })
    });
```

Have fun

Answer (score 0):

@olaf - I couldn't get their solution to work. Maybe Bootstrap 4 works different with `show` than Bootstrap 5

Took olaf answer and made it work with Bootstrap 5 / Vanilla

note: this only works for one element on the page with each class type.
if needed all the elements would use querySelectorAll and loop through setting each element class.

```
<div class="card">
 <div class="card-header" 
   data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#toggleme">
   Header - Click me
  </div>
    <div class="card-body collapse-sm" id="toggleme">
        Body
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    function responsiveCollapseView() {
        let desktopView = window.innerWidth;
        var el;
        if(el=document.querySelector('.collapse-xl, .collapse-lg, .collapse-md, .collapse-sm')) 
           el.classList.remove('collapse');
        if(desktopView >= "1200"){
            if(el = document.querySelector('.collapse-xl')) el.classList.add('collapse'); 
        }else if(desktopView >= "992"){
            if(el = document.querySelector('.collapse-lg')) el.classList.add('collapse'); 
        }else if(desktopView >= "768"){
            if(el = document.querySelector('.collapse-md')) el.classList.add('collapse'); 
        } else if(desktopView >= "576"){ 
            if(el = document.querySelector('.collapse-sm')) el.classList.add('collapse'); 
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
            responsiveCollapseView();
        }, true);
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        responsiveCollapseView();     
});
```

edit: quick and dirty for multiple elements

```
  
  function responsiveCollapseView(){
      let desktopView = window.innerWidth;
        var el;
   if(desktopView >= "1200"){
       if(el = document.querySelectorAll('.collapse-xl')) 
         loopAndAddClassCollapse(el); 
       }
  }

  function loopAndAddClassCollapse(list) {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
            list[i].classList.add("collapse");
        }
    }
    function loopAndRemoveClassCollapse(list) {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
            list[i].classList.remove("collapse");
        }
    }
```